# How to make redistribuatable package in python 3

Tags: installation, exe, software-distribution, redistributable

I am new to python tkinter. I am making my first application. I have mulitiple .py files and databases in MYSQL having mulitple tables. How to package that into installables. If I want to distribute that my software, I  don't want people to be forced to install python and mysql.

I have searched the internet. I know how to convert a single file into .exe but  that doesn't solve my purpose.

Comment: please elaborate how does converting to a single .exe not solve your problem?

Comment: I have multiple .py files related to each other. All have database connectivity with mysql. If i convert a single .py file into exe or if you suggest all of them into exe...will they work as one unit like a software

Comment: I don't see why they would not, maybe someone else who knows can chime in but I think they should. When you convert them all to an executable for example using pyinstaller the python interpreter is packaged inside the binary so I think they should run. May as well give it a try. I use https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ which is a nice tool to package your python program into an .exe (the tool uses pyinstaller)

Comment: Thanks probat....it worked. I am very very thankful to you for the timely help.

Comment: glad you got it to work, you are welcome.

Comment: My happiness was short-lived. It runs on my system only. On other systems it gives the error 'Failed to Execute Script index'